# Testcafe not running with typescript when installed locally

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

If I uninstall the local installation and install it globally it works, but I would prefer a local install for portability reasons.

This is a `yarn` project using `typescript` `v3.7.3` and I am using `testcafe` `v1.9.1`.

To install I ran:

`yarn add --dev testcafe`

and created a very simple test in `e2e-tests/test.ts`

When I try to run this test using `yarn run testcafe chrome e2e-tests/test.ts` I get the following stack trace:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ testcafe chrome e2e-tests/
ERROR TypeError: unknown: Property value expected type of string but got null
    at Object.validate (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:160:13)
    at validateField (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:24:9)
    at validate (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:17:3)
    at builder (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/builder.js:38:27)
    at Object.StringLiteral (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/generated/index.js:350:31)
    at enter (project/node_modules/react-hot-loader/dist/babel.development.js:605:29)
    at sourceRecord.<computed> (project/node_modules/react-hot-loader/dist/babel.development.js:688:16)
    at PluginPass.sourceRecord.<computed> (project/node_modules/react-hot-loader/dist/babel.development.js:687:14)
    at newFn (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:179:21)
    at NodePath._call (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
    at NodePath.call (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
    at NodePath.visit (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:84:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:140:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at traverse (project/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:66:12)
    at transformFile (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:107:29)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35:12)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.transform (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:27:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (project/node_modules/gensync/index.js:244:28)
    at Function.sync (project/node_modules/gensync/index.js:84:14)
    at Object.transform (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:36:54)
    at downgradeES (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/compile-client-function.js:53:28)
    at Object.compileClientFunction [as default] (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/compile-client-function.js:110:14)
    at ClientFunctionBuilder._getCompiledFnCode (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/client-functions/client-function-builder.js:114:41)
    at new ClientFunctionBuilder (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/client-functions/client-function-builder.js:30:36)
    at convertFilterToClientFunctionIfNecessary (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/client-functions/selectors/add-api.js:307:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/client-functions/selectors/add-api.js:342:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/client-functions/selectors/selector-builder.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/test-run/commands/actions.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/api/test-controller/index.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/api/wrap-test-function.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/api/structure/fixture.ts:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/api-based.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/formats/es-next/compiler.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/compilers.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/index.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/bootstrapper.ts:9:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/index.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Module._compile (project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:541:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at lazy (project/node_modules/import-lazy/index.js:2:51)
    at Object.construct (project/node_modules/import-lazy/index.js:18:11)
    at TestCafe._createRunner (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/testcafe.js:75:27)
    at TestCafe.createRunner (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/testcafe.js:90:21)
    at runTests (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/cli/cli.js:91:75)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at cli (project/node_modules/testcafe/src/cli/cli.js:161:13)
```

any help or insight would be super appreciated!

update:

I have chased the problem down to a specific babel plugin. If I remove `react-hot-loader/babel` it runs, not sure why yet. I am running into this new issue after I remove `react-hot-loader/babel`.

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ testcafe chrome e2e-tests/
The "browsers" option from the configuration file will be ignored.
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error.

Error: Using removed Babel 6 option: .resolveModuleSource - Use `babel-plugin-module-resolver@3`'s 'resolvePath' options
    at throwUnknownError (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:121:11)
    at project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:108:5
    at validateNested (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:84:21)
    at validate (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:75:10)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:76:50)
    at loadFullConfig (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:57:46)
    at Function.transform (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:25:45)
    at evaluateSync (project/node_modules/gensync/index.js:244:28)
    at Function.sync (project/node_modules/gensync/index.js:84:14)
    at Object.transform (project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:36:54)
```

Comment: The error stack suggests that TestCafe tries to use Babel 7 for some reason, while only Babel 6 is supported at the moment. If you have Babel 7 modules listed in your `package.json` (`@babel/core`, `@babel/cli`), their removal can resolve the issue. I cannot reproduce the issue with a minimal `package.json`: [https://gist.github.com/AndreyBelym/b55d8ef66b22fd6b1263edce6f548665](https://gist.github.com/AndreyBelym/b55d8ef66b22fd6b1263edce6f548665). So, could you please create a sample project that can be used to reproduce the issue or share your `package.json`?

Comment: Also, you can ensure that there is no `node_modules` directory in directories that are parents to your project directory.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyBelym! This project is using babel 7 and I'm not sure we'll be able to downgrade so I might have to choose something other than testcafe. I'm gonna dig into babel 7 support for testcafe and see if there are any tricks that can be used to work around this issue. Thanks again!